# Is there an adjective for "untruthful, especially when pretending to know more than one actually does"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, pejorative-language

I originally thought of the word "disingenuous," except that my dictionary gives the definition as "not candid or sincere, typically by pretending that one knows less about something than one really does." I'm looking for a word that's similar in meaning, but with an emphasis on pretending to know something (rather than pretending not to know something).

Example sentence: Citing statistics he made up, the _____ salesman claimed that his weight-loss pills were miracle workers.

Comment: If the intent is to appear smarter than one actually is, I'd go with "pretentious".

Comment: I've seen some answers on StackExchange like that.  Someone giving an answer without really knowing anything about it.  Of course we always reject such answers, right?

Comment: IMO, *salesmen* only needs adjectives when this is not what you mean. *He kept trying to [sell me / lead me on]*.

Comment: I'm not making this an answer because I don't think it's widely used these days, but it fits quite well: **mountebank** *a fast-talking crook pretending to be an expert* https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mountebank

Comment: In other news, I'm just *shining you on*.

Comment: The example sentence seems inconsistent with the given definition.  A salesman who makes up statistics isn't pretending to know _more_ than he does, rather he's testing if his audience knows _less_ than he does. (No serious pseudo-expert would be satisfied with made up facts, rather they'd memorize rote statistics and stock answers, without of course, having much grasp of what these rote memorizations mean, or how they were arrived at.  It's the same with a student cheating on a test -- they don't know the topic tested, but they might have memorized correct answers.)

Comment: 'Manager' is the word you looking for LOL ;)

Comment: A colloquial term that fits the description (and works in the context of the example sentence) is *scumbag*.

Answer (score 19):

[Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charlatanic) defines the word **charlatanic** (alternative form **charlatanical**) as

> :  of or like a charlatan : marked by or given to pretension and quackery

In turn, [the same source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charlatan) defines the noun **charlatan** as

> : a person who falsely pretends to know or be something in order to deceive people

I'd be a little hesitant to use **charlatanic** or **charlatanical**,
since they are very infrequently used; I'd worry that readers might think I had just coined the word.
I'd rather work the noun into the sentence, for example,

> Citing statistics he made up, the salesman, **that charlatan**, claimed that his weight-loss pills were miracle workers.

But the adjectives do exist in some dictionaries if an adjective is really what you need.

Comment: Charlatans and quacks are erroneous, but needn't necessarily be wholly (or even partly) insincere; a charlatan might be overconfident, over-celebrated, oblivious, jealous, paranoid, or delusional, with some "white lies" on the side.

Comment: @agc Your evidence? A _quack_ might sometimes merely be ignorant of his or her own incompetence, but I don't recall _charlatan_ used that way.

Comment: Quacks need not be _incompetent_, they may just be strenuously wrong about things -- but they could be _competently_ wrong, i.e. perfect technique, wrong premise.   Re _charlatan_ see Pope Brock's excellent study of [John R. Brinkley](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ABookSources&isbn=0307339882).

Comment: @agc "John R. Brinkley–America’s most brazen young con man"  https://books.google.com/books?id=vnu6CCfeylkC&dq=isbn:0307339882&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO1OTmuM_MAhVCFj4KHSzsBK8Q6AEIHTAA -- yes, _that's_ a glowing endorsement of sincerity. And I don't think we need to debate what it means for a quack to be competent; _quack_ is not an exact synonym for _charlatan_ and I did not suggest it in the answer.

Comment: Rewind: "...needn't necessarily be wholly (or even partly) insincere...".   [Just like _bona fide_ doctors, JRB desired a high surgical batting average, (i.e. _cures_), and in that he was sincere -- alas his dreadful choice of medical innovations made him a _de facto_ serial killer, but such is the power of undeserved medical fame, that he never quite saw himself as we do.]

Comment: Clarification:  a person can be _both_ quack _and_ charlatan.

Comment: As you say, _charlatanic_ and _charlatanical_ are very unusual words. They appear in Merriam-Webster's unabridged online dictionary (not MW's Learner's Dictionary, I think) but not in the _Eleventh Collegiate_, indicating that those forms are not in mainstream use. A Google Books search for "[charlatan doctor](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22albert%20einstein%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22charlatan+doctor%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=170)" draws almost 200 matches. "Charlatanical doctor" yields very few non-dictionary matches, and "charlatanic doctor" just one.

Answer (score 12):

> [...] the **bullshitting** salesman claimed [...] .

> **bullshit**
>   [...]
>   4. (intr) to talk in an exaggerated or foolish manner.
>   5. (tr) to talk bullshit to (a person).
>
> *Usage: Bullshit was formerly considered to be taboo, and it was labelled as such in older editions of Collins English Dictionary. However, it has now become acceptable in speech, although some older or more conservative people may object to its use.*
>   —  [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bullshitting):

Note: For a less objectionable variation (if you can rework sentence to use a noun), consider **bull** - actually an [older form](http://blog.inkyfool.com/2012/08/bull-bullshit-and-ts-eliot.html), rather than a contraction.

Comment: "I don't have a cow, I don't need any of your bull"

Comment: "Hot air" can be used as a more polite alternative, e.g. "Nonsense, that man is full of... erm, *hot air*, vicar"

Comment: As defined in detail by Harry Frankfurt: http://www.stoa.org.uk/topics/bullshit/pdf/on-bullshit.pdf

Answer (score 8):

I like the word ***deceitful*** in this case:

> guilty of or involving deceit; deceiving or misleading others.
>   [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deceitful)

In the above definition, they give this example:

> charged the store owner with such deceitful practices as inflating the list prices for items only so he could put them on sale at drastically reduced prices

In your case:

> Citing statistics he made up, the **deceitful** salesman claimed that his weight-loss pills were miracle workers.

He is knowingly passing false information.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps *dissembling*. *Oxford Online* defines *[dissemble](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dissemble)* as

> Conceal one’s true motives, feelings, or beliefs:
>   *an honest, sincere person with no need to dissemble*

Or you could just say *lying* or *fraudulent*.

If you want something a bit more metaphoric, you could use *[snake oil](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snake-oil)*

> A product, policy, etc. of little real worth or value that is promoted as the solution to a problem:
>   *the new tax plan was denounced as snake oil*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

In your example, it has an especially nice ring

> Citing statistics he made up, the *snake oil* salesman claimed that his weight-loss pills were miracle workers.

Comment: I find *snake-oil* especially apt in regards to sales, as that's where the term originated (AFAIK)

Answer (score 5):

A general word for "pretending to know more than one actually does" is "pretentious," which is defined in the New Oxford American Dictionary as:

> Attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed.

This doesn't connote deliberate, blatant falsehoods; rather it suggests plausible-sounding invention in place of knowledge.  It doesn't *quite* fit your example sentence.

You could also just use "dishonest."

Answer (score 3):

You could also consider bluffer or bluffing.

> "[bluff](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bluff)".
>
> try to deceive someone as to one's abilities or intentions.

In the context of the question it would be the *abilities* part of the definition that is of relevance (as in the "[bluffer's guide](https://bluffers.com)" series of books where the title refers to feigning unwarranted expertise).

Comment: I think that this is typically more gentle than the OPs question asked for, but if someone wants a gentle variety, this one certainly fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, ***wily***

> ***wily** (and **guileful**) stress an attempt to ensnare or entrap; they usually imply treacherous astuteness or sagacity and a lack of scruples regarding the means to one's end.*
>
> [M-W's Dictionary of Synonyms](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA749&lpg=PA749&dq=%22imply+treacherous+astuteness+or+sagacity+and+a+lack+of%22&source=bl&ots=7cu7Z6Mkkv&sig=75b-_YNHgvB3_AtUeUf3u85dw1M&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgiaKk883MAhWmC8AKHWfmCZIQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=%22wily%22&f=false)
>
> ***wily** implies skill and deception in maneuvering.*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wily)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use ***[untrustworthy](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unreliable)***:

> - not worthy of being trusted: untrustworthy witnesses.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [shyster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/shyster).

> : a dishonest person
>   especially : a dishonest lawyer or politician — often used before another noun

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of a persuasive person, consider:

> The **silver-tongued** salesman claimed that his weight-loss pills
>   were miracle workers.

Definition: able to speak in a way that makes other people do or believe what you want them to do or believe (*informal usually pejorative*).

Answer (score 1):

Self-aggrandizing is a candidate I've not seen mentioned yet that would be a decent fit.

One of the definitions of *[aggrandize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggrandize)* from Mirram-Webster is:

> to make appear great or greater

...

> Nowadays, both noun and verb are regularly paired (somewhat disparagingly) with the prefix self- to refer to individuals bent on glorifying themselves

Answer (score 0):

There's no adequate *single adjective* in English that specifically describes willfully and knowingly pretending to know more than one actually does.

Combining two words might work:  pseudo-expert, pretend-scholar, techno-pretender, puff-peddler, cuff-notes, fake-brained, glib-grader, cerebral impersonator...

Answer (score 0):

**Not really an answer** in the case that the person actually knows he is misleading someone. But that can be horribly difficult to tell sometimes.

If it is the case that the person honestly thinks he is knowledgeable and trying to help by showing his knowledge, you could say he **has climbed mount stupid**. It is a phase in learning when confidence has grown much faster than actual skill so a person actually can think they know lots but it really isn't warranted.

Answer (score -1):

Try [crafty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Crafty)

> marked by subtlety and guile.

Subtlety means the quality of being difficult to detect or analyze and guile means the use of clever and usually dishonest methods to achieve something.

Comment: I think that's a false definition for "guile"; the New Oxford American has it as "sly or cunning intelligence."  It doesn't have the same connotations at all as "dishonest."

Comment: Simply claiming to be smarter or more knowledgeable than you actually are doesn't strike me as an example of craftiness or guile.

Comment: @Wildcard see the definition guile at Merriam Webster.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Where is "knowledgeable and smarter"? It is neither stated nor implied.

Comment: @vickyace In the question. `Is there an adjective for “untruthful, especially when pretending to know more than one actually does”?`

Comment: @HopelessN00b maybe craftiness is a result of him being untruthful while pretending to know more than he actually does. That could be a possibility.

Comment: Well, anything's possible. Maybe he's also a serial killer. But regardless, I don't see how "crafty" applies here. All we have is that he's dishonestly claiming to be more knowledgeable than he is. How is that an example of craftiness?  It doesn't strike me as clever or subtle, or anything along those lines.  <shrug>

Comment: @vickyace, fair enough; I still think it's incorrect, but perhaps it's my misunderstood word, not yours.  I'll check it out in the Webster's Third New International Dictionary later on (I have it at home).

Answer (score -1):

It's not one word, but if someone is withholding information, you can say they aren't being [upfront](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/upfront).

Comment: Agreed that it's not one word.  You should really include the space, don't you think?

Answer (score -3):

For your example sentence, you could use 'confident' as in 'confidence man'. Wouldn't work in a general sense though.

> of, relating to, or adept at swindling by false promises, e.g.: a confidence game; a confidence man

Comment: You're confusing "confident" and one particular usage of "confidence".  "Confident" does **not** imply dishonesty as asked in the question.

Comment: My answer included that. In the example sentence, talking about a lying salesman, the meaning of confident would be quite apparent. I agree the general meaning of confident is different. But a 'con man' is exactly the kind of person the OP was asking about, who implies he knows more than what he does.

Comment: Your answer was unclear.  You said "you could use '*confident*'", but then you referred to '*confidence*', appearing to equate the two.  And you've given no explanation or reference about what your suggested terms mean.  If part of your answer is a quotation from another source, then please reference the source.

Comment: A con man is a man that performs a confidence trick. Nobody ever rephrases that as "confidence man".

Comment: Golfing for terms...  *Over*confident isn't quite it, as overconfidence is usually oblivious, and not a pretense.  *Pseudo*confident connotes obliviousness as well.  _Mock  confidence_ implies jocularity.  _Sham_ confidence implies theatricality.  _Proactive_ confidence might be misunderstood, and be taken literally rather than ironically.  Going the other way, *sub*confident, in the sense of *substandard*...