# What is it called to someone who talks about deep or big topics?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What is it called to someone who talks about deep or big topics to sound smart, or just to impress others around him, even though he has no idea about anything?

Comment: We use special letters, BS.  Also, hot air, pontificating, blowhard, and the current pot-calling-the-kettle-black showboat.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. From the SWR tag info: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Is there an adjective for “untruthful, especially when pretending to know more than one actually does”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324562/is-there-an-adjective-for-untruthful-especially-when-pretending-to-know-more-t/324690#324690).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's dictionary, **pretentious** is defined as,"Attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed."

Answer (score 2):

There are few single words that encapsulate this behavior in the English language, however, there are plenty of terms. Here are some single words, as I believe this is what you're asking for:

> #### Hubristic:
>
> ```
> Excessive pride or self-confidence; arrogance.
> ```
>
> #### Cocksure:
>
> ```
> Displaying or marked by rude boldness; having or showing a mind free from doubt.
> ```